# Unable to get beyond 'Login Error' publishing to Cordova Plugin Registry

Tags: cordova, plugman

I'm trying to publish an update to a plugin already in the public Cordova repository at plugins.cordova.io. Calls to `plugman publish` are rejected with a 'login error'. Based on other information online, I tried removing ~/.plugman and re-running `plugman adduser`. That command succeeds but I still get a login error on subsequent attempts to publish.

It's certainly possible that I don't have the correct password, but there does not seem to be any way to perform a password reset. I also noticed that running `plugman adduser` does not seem to store any credential information in ~/.plugman but it does create/update ~/.npmrc. I do have a separate account on npmjs so I don't know if they have interacted somehow.

So right now I'm completely locked out of the public repository. I do still have access to the email address associated with the plugin but without any password reset procedure I'm not sure where to go next. I didn't see any contact details on the registry site itself.

Comment: Maybe it depends on this blog post of cordova: http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html

Comment: Many thanks, Joerg. I'm still not sure why the Cordova Registry isn't working but as the future is npm and I can successfully publish there then I'm all set. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved downgrade plugman version

npm install -g plugman@0.23.0

Comment: Can you explain your answer? Usually downgrading software is a last resort, whereas you seem to be suggesting it with no explanation.

Comment: I cant explain! I tried on 2 windows computers and one Mac OS and i had the same problem. I dont knwo why..

Comment: I can confirm that this solves the problem. It looks like 23.1 is a stepping stone towards moving the registry over to npm and broke compatibility with the old Cordova registry along the way. So unless there's a new release of plugman that repairs Cordova registry support (and that probably isn't a priority for them...) downgrading is a good solution.